# Same values are saving into DB multiple times,Even though another list is present in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate, foreach-loop-container

I am messed up with this issue,Please any one can help on this.
I will get nested Json as input to controller,Which is then converted to MarketPrice object type.Everything is working fine,Only while saving am facing issue.The first record will be saved multiple times.But in forecah loop the second time another values will be shown while debugging.

**MarketPrice.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MarketPrice")
public class MarketPrice {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "itemId")
private Long itemId;

@Column(name = "state")
private String state;

@Column(name = "district")
private String district;

@Transient
public Items currentItem;

@Column(name="itemName")
private String itemName;

@Column(name="minimumPrice")
private Float minimumPrice;

@Column(name="maximumPrice")
private Float maximumPrice;
}
```

**Items.java**

```
public class Items implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2428562977284114465L;

    public String itemName;
    public Float minimumPrice;
    public Float maximumPrice;
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/save"} , method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public MarketPrice bulkSaveMarketAnalysis(@RequestBody 
        String marketPrices, HttpServletResponse response,
        HttpServletRequest request) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException, JSONException{

    MarketPrice marketPrice1 = new MarketPrice();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    MarketPrice marketPrice = gson.fromJson(marketPrices, MarketPrice.class);
    if(marketPrice.getState() != null){
    String marketDataResponse = analyserService.saveListOfMarketPrice(marketPrice);
    System.out.println(marketDataResponse);
    return marketPrice1;
}
```

**DAO.java**

```
public String saveListOfMarketPrice(MarketPrice marketPrice) {
    final Session session = getSession();
   Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    marketPrice.setAnalysisDate(new Date());
    for (Items item : marketPrice.marketPrices) {
       marketPrice.currentItem = item;
       marketPrice.setItemName(marketPrice.currentItem.getItemName());
       marketPrice.setUnitofPrice(marketPrice.currentItem.getUnitofPrice());
       marketPrice.setMinimumPrice(marketPrice.currentItem.getMinimumPrice());
       marketPrice.setMaximumPrice(marketPrice.currentItem.getMaximumPrice());
        session.save(marketPrice);
        tx.commit();
        }
     session.close();
     return "success";
}
```

**Json data to controller**

```
{"marketPrices":[{"itemName":"Grapes","unitofPrice":"Kg","minimumPrice":"11","maximumPrice":"22"},{"itemName":"Mango","unitofPrice":"Quintal","minimumPrice":"55","maximumPrice":"66"}],"state":"xyz","district":4,"marketPlace":5001,"marketName":"Apmc","category":"Fruits"}
```

Issue am facing here is only one record will added into DB multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using that same reference marketPrice again. You have to create new references in order to create new rows otherwise it'll keep on updating that same managed entity. Also, commit your transaction after saving all the entities.

```
public String saveListOfMarketPrice(MarketPrice marketPrice) {
    final Session session = getSession();
   Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    for (Items item : marketPrice.marketPrices) {
       MarketPrice marketPriceToSaveInDBAsNewRow = new MarketPrice();
       marketPriceToSaveInDBAsNewRow.setAnalysisDate(new Date());
       marketPriceToSaveInDBAsNewRow.currentItem = item;
       marketPriceToSaveInDBAsNewRow.setItemName(marketPriceToSaveInDBAsNewRow.currentItem.getItemName());
       marketPriceToSaveInDBAsNewRow.setUnitofPrice(marketPriceToSaveInDBAsNewRow.currentItem.getUnitofPrice());
       marketPriceToSaveInDBAsNewRow.setMinimumPrice(marketPriceToSaveInDBAsNewRow.currentItem.getMinimumPrice());
       marketPriceToSaveInDBAsNewRow.setMaximumPrice(marketPriceToSaveInDBAsNewRow.currentItem.getMaximumPrice());
        session.save(marketPriceToSaveInDBAsNewRow);

        }
     tx.commit();
     session.close();
     //session.getTransaction().commit();
     return "success";
}
```

Comment: This is a new variable which is created in every loop. The name of the variable describes its usage.

Comment: While using this except currentItem variables all are set to null which are in marketPrice object

Comment: Both are same. Edited

Comment: Its working i.e current item names are different and saved,But values in state district marketPlace marketName are set to null,so again i have to set it from marketPrice..? You can see i have edited ans

Comment: Those are null because your are not saving them in the `saveListOfMarketPrice` method.

Comment: no am saving those also.. i have set those values now its working fine..Thank you so much